# Return classes, objects, functions and constants as their original types from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I imported everything from a Python module. Say;

```py
from module import *
```

The module has a mix of classes, functions, objects (singletons), and constants. I want to know what are all the classes/functions/objects/constants available specifically.

By using `dir()` I get the mixed Python list of all classes, objects, functions, and constants as names. For example, `dir()` gives an out of names in current scope after importing the module;

```py
['Class1', 'Class2', 'obj1', 'func1', 'obj2', 'Class3', 'func2', 'CONST1']
```

Now if I need to know the type a name from a module, I need to manually check their types whether a name is class/function/object/constant using;

```py
type(Class1)
type(obj1)
type(func1)
type(CONST1)
```

I want something to get all the classes/functions/objects/constants as their original type from the module import. For example;

```py
get_classes()
```

Should return;

```
[Class1, Class2, Class3]
```

Where, `Class1`, `Class2`, and `Class3` are returned as classes but not just their names. So that `type(get_classes()[0]` should return `type` or `isinstance(get_classes()[0], type)` should return `True`. Similar outputs are desired for functions, objects and constants too.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

All classes are instances of `type`, so you can do:

```
def get_classes(my_list):
    return [i for i in my_list if isinstance(i, type)]
```

Comment: I was wrapping around my head thinking to something using `isinstance`. Thank you so much for the answer. Even though it's right, answer by @aaossa using `inspect.isclass` will give more readability to the code viewer.

Comment: @kunarapupriyatham you really should just use `isinstance` with `type`, not sure why you think that is less readable, "type" and "class" are essentially synonymous, and `inspect.isclass` is a holdover from python 2

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga for the more information. I thought that `isclass` function name make it clearly look like we're checking whether it's a class. But, as it's holdover as you said, I'll prefer `isinstance`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`inspect.isclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass), which according to the docs:

> Return True if the object is a class, whether built-in or created in Python code.

So, your function could use a list comprehension using the `inspect.isclass` function like this:

```py
def get_classes(my_list):
    return [value for value in my_list if inspect.isclass(value)]
```

Notice that `inspect.isclass` uses `isinstance` internally. You can confirm it seeing the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/inspect.py#L191-L197) in GitHub:

```
def isclass(object):
    """Return true if the object is a class.
    Class objects provide these attributes:
        __doc__         documentation string
        __module__      name of module in which this class was defined"""
    return isinstance(object, type)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into the isinstance() function in python.